# Weird Behavior for replace fragments in single activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm facing a weird behavior when replacing fragments in the same activity, this what happens:

-I have a `signinFragment` which is the default fragment in the `AhuthenticationActivity`.

-I have an interface to switch between fragments when i click at button like `signUp`.

-I implement the interface in the Activity and check for the number passed for the interface function then open the specified fragment.

```java
@Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(view-> startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class)));
        signUpTextView.setOnClickListener(view-> listener.switchFragment(Constants.SIGNUP_FRAGMENT));
        forgetPasswordTextView.setOnClickListener(view-> listener.switchFragment(Constants.FORGET_PASSWORD_FRAGMENT));
        return rootView;
    }
```

- Authentication Activity

```java
@Override
    public void switchFragment(int fragment) {
        switch (fragment){
            case Constants.SIGNUP_FRAGMENT: {
                Log.d(TAG,"SignUP Launched"); // this shows SignUP Launched
                                              //ForgetPassword Launched i don't know why?!
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Authentication_Activity_Container, signUpFragment).addToBackStack(TAG).commit();
            }case Constants.FORGET_PASSWORD_FRAGMENT:{
                Log.d(TAG,"ForgetPassword Launched"); //this works fine ForgetPassword Launched
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Authentication_Activity_Container, forgetPasswordFragment).addToBackStack(TAG).commit();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()>0){
            fragmentManager.popBackStack(TAG, POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

so what happens is when i click on `signUp` the `Log` shows `signUp Launched` then `ForgetPassword Launched` and when i click on `forgetPassword` the `Log` shows `ForgetPassword Launched`, i can't figure out why this happens?

Comment: there is no `break` in your switch statement between cases so in both cases the last case will always execute.

Comment: OMG, sorry for this stupid mistake.

Comment: No problem, sometimes code needs another pair of eyes to "see the wood for the trees".

Answer (score 1):

You have missed break between the switch-cases.

Your last code block should be:

```
@Override
    public void switchFragment(int fragment) {
        switch (fragment){
            case Constants.SIGNUP_FRAGMENT: {
                Log.d(TAG,"SignUP Launched"); // this shows SignUP Launched
                                              //ForgetPassword Launched i don't know why?!
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Authentication_Activity_Container, signUpFragment).addToBackStack(TAG).commit();
            }
break;
case Constants.FORGET_PASSWORD_FRAGMENT:{
                Log.d(TAG,"ForgetPassword Launched"); //this works fine ForgetPassword Launched
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Authentication_Activity_Container, forgetPasswordFragment).addToBackStack(TAG).commit();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()>0){
            fragmentManager.popBackStack(TAG, POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```